# Параллельная загрузка ImageView

Tags: android

Есть 16 ImageView, в них я загружаю циклом большие изображения из локальных файлов. Сейчас загрузка идет поочередно и медленно. Как сделать, чтобы загрузка шла во все 16 ImageView параллельно и одновременно? А также можно ли ускорить процесс загрузки?, так как мне нужны из больших изображений маленькие(200х200), что я делаю через BitmapFactory.Options. Приведите пожалуйста примером кода если можно.

```
public int[] img_Foto_frVM_16 = new int[]{R.id.iv_foto_frVM_1, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_2, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_3, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_4,
        R.id.iv_foto_frVM_5, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_6, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_7, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_8,
        R.id.iv_foto_frVM_9, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_10, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_11, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_12,
        R.id.iv_foto_frVM_13, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_14, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_15, R.id.iv_foto_frVM_16};


public void Load_ImagesView_16_ViewMarker(String i_var_4) { // i_var_4 - строка ссылок на изображения


        int[] img_n = mapsActivity.fr_View_Marker.img_Foto_frVM_16;
        final String[] q = i_var_4.split("\n"); // для построчного чтения через перенос

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) mapsActivity.findViewById(img_n[i]);

                //выбираемый файл изображения
                final File my_file = new File(q[i]); //your image file path
                final Bitmap imgBitmap;
                BitmapFactory.Options option = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                option.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mapsActivity.full_Path_catalog_folder_Gallery + my_file.getAbsolutePath(), option);
                float max = Math.max(((float) option.outWidth) / 200.0f, ((float) option.outHeight) / 200.0f);
                if (max > 1.0f) {
                    option.inSampleSize = (int) max;
                }
                option.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                imgBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mapsActivity.full_Path_catalog_folder_Gallery + my_file.getAbsolutePath(), option);
                // поток
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(imgBitmap);
                        imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

        }

}
```

Comment: не пробовали использовать ListView или RecyclerView ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку Picasso. Она сделает всю работу за вас.

Для этого пропишите в `Graddle`

```
dependencies {
     ...
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'    
}
```

В коде `import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;`

и в нужный момент - `Picasso.with(YourActivity.this).load(my_file).into(imgView);`

после `load(file)`, если необходимо, можете прописать `.resize(width,height)`